# Coldfusion 2016 running some code 3 times

Tags: coldfusion

I'm currently running Coldfusion 2016 (although this behaviour has occurred on Coldfusion 10).

In a very basic script:

```
<cfoutput>
    #getTickCount()#
</cfoutput>

<cflog text = "#getTickCount()#" type = "information" application = "yes" file = "testlog">

<cfabort>
```

The cfoutput tag prints out one tick count, as expected. The cf log however, writes out 3 lines with a different tick count. This is the same for cfquery. The Coldfusion code seems to be running certain CFML tags 3 times.

Has anyone seen this before? I've tried completely uninstalling Coldfusion (hence the upgrade from CF 10 to CF 2016). I've tried cflog and cfquery to both SQL Server and MySQL. This problem has me completely stumped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried eliminating the browser layer - for example if you are using Chrome is it calling the page 3 times due to a pre loader or an extension etc.

Comment: Culprit found - HTTP Headers extension in Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/mhbpoeinkhpajikalhfpjjafpfgjnmgk